# @ValueRangeProvider annotation on a Planning Entity field

Tags: optaplanner

When defining the @ValueRangeProvider annotation on a Planning Entity, can I put it on the field, or  is it only supported on the getter method?

Comment: Why don't you just try? This is trivial and will be detected by the Java compiler. Also, the class has a Javadoc which answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Any annotation that works on a method should also work on a field. If it doesn't, create an RFE jira, it is a clear API gap that we would like to fix.

Like Lukas said, just try it. And paste the code you tried here if it doesn't work :)